# Getting a google refresh token with HelloJs and Python

Tags: javascript, python, google-api

You are not able to retrieve refresh tokens via javascript/HelloJS alone. How might I retrieve it in the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a google refresh token from the hello.js, requires the use of a shim. But first you must use explicit login and set response type to code in your hello js login call

`hello.login({'response_type':'code'})`

For more details on the shim, here are notes from the author of hello.js https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js/issues/350